# error with feed_dict in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, summary

I am a new learner of tensorflow, I got error for my following code.

```
merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(init)
     writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('logs/', sess.graph)
     for epoch in range(21):
         for batch in range(n_batch):
             batch_xs, batch_ys = minst.train.next_batch(batch)
             summary, _ = sess.run([merged, train_step], feed_dict={x:batch_xs, y:batch_ys})
```

the error is the last line. tensorflow gives this error msg:

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1/y_input' with dtype float and shape [?,10]
 [[Node: input_1/y_input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,10], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-18-794785aaa402> in <module>()
      60         for batch in range(n_batch):
      61             batch_xs, batch_ys = minst.train.next_batch(batch)
 ---> 62             summary, _ = sess.run([merged, train_step], feed_dict={x:batch_xs, y:batch_ys})
```

please help me figure out what is wrong. thanks.

Comment: have you tried "feed_dict={x:batch_xs, y_input:batch_ys}" or "feed_dict={x:batch_xs, input_1/y_input:batch_ys}"?

Comment: How your x and y are assigned? They should be tensors, like tf.placeholder(...)

Comment: yes, I use placeholder to do it. see below.

Comment: x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name="x_input")
     y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name="y_input")